# Postcode Anywhere (PCA Predict) not working on contact or account form in Dynamics 365 mobile app

Tags: android, postal-code, dynamics-365, dynamics365-app-mobile

Was testing PCA Predict on my android using Dynamics 365 for mobile and it doesn't work. It definitely works in the desktop client though.

I debugged the code using the chrome debugger whilst previewing the mobile client online and got the following error messages:

[image]

I have a feeling that it could be because the fields are mapped for the composite address field and the mobile client doesn't support. PCA Predict said they haven't done any testing with the Dynamics 365 app so they cannot help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I called them up and they said Dynamics 365 Mobile is not supported.